# How do I parse a hex-int from a string to an Integer?

Tags: java, parsing, integer

I have no problem in writing this: (it also doesn't give any errors)

```
int hex = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

The integer has to have an alpha value also!

*But* when I try to do this:

```
Integer hex = Integer.parseInt("0xFFFFFFFF");
// Or I try this:
Integer hex = Integer.parseInt("FFFFFFFF");
```

I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0xFFFFFFFF"` thrown!

Why is this not working?

I'm guessing that there is some other way to parse hex integers that I am just not realizing, and I really need to be able to parse hex from string for a program I am making.

Comment: As a side note, you should probably go with `int hex = ...` instead of `Integer hex = ...`. The capitalized one is the object form, instead of the primitive form. While both will work, attempting to use the `Integer` as an `int` will force Java to unbox and rebox repeatedly, slowing down your application and taking up more memory, neither of which is a very good idea. It's also not very good coding practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a separate function where you can define the radix:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

`Integer.parseInt(x)` simply calls `Integer.parseInt(x, 10)`, so you have to specify a radix 10 number.

In order to parse a hex string, you would simply have to use the following (note that the 0x prefix is not allowed):

```
Integer.parseInt("FFFFFFF", 16);
```