# Parse a C-style programmer's integer in Java

Tags: java, parsing, integer, radix

This one is short, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Is there a jdk routine that can parse a `String` to an `int`, and *autodetect* and convert C-style programming conventions:

- 123 (decimal)
- 0x1ABC (hex)
- 0x1abc (hex)
- 0777 (octal)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Let me be clear here, I know I can handroll this method. I already did so! I know what a radix is and about `Integer.parse(..., radix)`! What I am asking is, hasn't the JDK already got a method that handles all the cases. A one-liner for the whole lot...

Comment: Well, decimal and octal are easy. No offense, but you couldn't have looked that hard. All the number classes have a `parse` method.

Comment: Key search term: radix

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066487/how-do-i-parse-a-hex-int-from-a-string-to-an-integer/27066710#27066710

Comment: @Carcigenicate I know all that, I already looked that hard. see my edit.

Comment: @drrob Sorry to assume otherwise. My bad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate haha no worries it's my bad, I realize on reading back how my original wording was too vague!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember such function in standard JDK.

If you want to auto detect style, you cat write helper function with `switch-case` or `Strategy pattern`.

First, check if number string starts with `0x`, if no - check if it starts with `0` at all. But this won't work if you will have binary number. But there are no such in your question ^_^.

See [Integer.parse(String s, radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) method.

---

Attaching sample code:

```
public class RadixDetector {

    private static final int RADIX_HEX = 16;
    private static final int RADIX_OCTAL = 8;

    public static int detectRadix(String number) {

        if (number.toLowerCase().startsWith("0x") && isValidHex(number)) {
            return RADIX_HEX;
        } else if (number.startsWith("0") && isValidOctal(number)) {
            return RADIX_OCTAL;
        } else {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Unknown or unable to detect radix for: " + number);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidHex(String number) {
        Pattern hexPattern = Pattern.compile("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+");
        return hexPattern.matcher(number).matches();
    }

    public static boolean isValidOctal(String number) {
        Pattern hexPattern = Pattern.compile("0[1-7][0-7]*");
        return hexPattern.matcher(number).matches();
    }
}
```

And tests:

```
public class NumberRadixTests {

    @Test
    public void testRadixDetection() {
        assertEquals(16, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0xabcd"));
        assertEquals(16, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0xABCD"));
        assertEquals(16, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0xAFFF"));
        assertEquals(16, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0x0"));
        assertEquals(16, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0X0"));
        assertEquals(16, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0XFFF"));
        assertEquals(8, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0123"));
        assertEquals(8, RadixDetector.detectRadix("011"));
        assertEquals(8, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0777"));
        assertEquals(8, RadixDetector.detectRadix("0666"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testHexRegex() {
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0xabcd"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0Xabcd"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0xAbcd"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0xa0cd"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0x9bc1"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0x9bc1"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("x9bc1"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0xbtc1"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0xx9bc1"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("00x9bc1"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0x9pc1"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("0x"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidHex("077"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOctalRegex() {
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("077"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("067"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("07777"));
        assertTrue(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("017"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("08"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("8"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("777"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("0x"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("08"));
        assertFalse(RadixDetector.isValidOctal("01238"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Aye, I've handrolled a method using that... but seems a common enough use case that there ought to be a one-liner method (rather than test each case myself)...

Comment: @drrob sorry, removed redundant info, rewritten answer

Comment: Very much appreciated, but I already did that. I want to *autodetect*, not have to reinvent what seems to me a common case. I am guessing the answer is no, you have to write out each case...

Comment: @drrob truly say, I don't remember such function in standard JDK.

Comment: yeah looks like not :C

Comment: @drrob Autodetecting integer radix is pretty far from a common use case.

Comment: @Kayaman maybe not, but I felt like I was reinventing the wheel writing out the switch statement. I hate that...

Comment: @drrob does C standard libraries have such method / functionality ?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I don't think so, but then to me the C standard libraries, excluding POSIX extensions, are incredibly limited compared to JDK. C-style numbers are used in various scripting languages as they have become a sort of defacto standard way of representing different programmers numbers.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as I think someone would have said quite quickly, if they new a JDK method for this. Thanks!

Comment: @drrob happy coding!